# Python module import fails when projects starts as service

Tags: python, service, python-import

A project (Python 3.6) consists of some folders. In some files there is scope extension like

```
sys.path.append('../foo')
```

due to import not from the same directory where the file is.

It works from PyCharm and when the application starts from a command line as `python.exe app.py`
But this scope extension for import doesn't work when projects starts as service. It is checked when starting project with pm2 utilite and just starting as service. Scope extension for import just doesn't work and import fails.

The way to avoid the error is to change the relative paths in `sys.path.append` with absolute like

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent)+'/foo')
```

After this changes the code starts as service without errors.

I suspect that relative paths don't work when the application running as service. But why?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.pqth.append()` method simply append it's argument as it is. Thus, if you run it in Python console, you can see the result like this:

```
>>> sys.path.append("../foo")
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/yunbo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '../foo']
```

When you run your code in PyCharm, it may works fine. But if you run your code as a service, CWD is not the same as your project folder(or some sub path). Your code will look for the `CWD/../foo` and that won't be there. That's why your code fails to run as a service.

Using `sys.path` or `pathlib` is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your project as a service using pm2, what is current working directory your python interpreter is in? `os.getcwd()`.
It's likely not in your project root.

According to https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#general
pm2 can be configured to set `cwd` - so you need to set it to your project root.